# How to insert the array value inside for loop in php

Tags: php, mysql, arrays, for-loop, sql-insert

Here I am having array value inside the for loop, and insert query outside the for loop.
Need to know how to connect the array value inside the insert query

Here My code is

```
    $start = php2MySqlTime(js2PhpTime($st)); 
    $count= (strtotime($et) - strtotime($st)) /60;
    $count1 = $count/30; //echo $count1; 

    for($i=0;$i<=$count1;$i++){

        $start = date("Y-m-d H:i:s",strtotime("+30 minutes",strtotime($start))).',';

        echo $start;
    }

     $sql = "insert into `jqcalendar` (`list_id`,`totaltime`, `isalldayevent`) 
     values ('"
     .$list_id."', '".$start."', '".mysql_real_escape_string($ade)."'
     )";
```

By this code it's inserting only one value in array, But I need full array values to be inserted

Comment: where it is storing one value in array and where you want to store full array values...??? If you want to store it in DB put your `$sql` query in for loop..

Answer (score 1):

Try this..Its just example to show you logic

```
$qry = 'INSERT INTO table (FirstName, LastName) VALUES ';
for($i=0;$i<=$count1;$i++){
    $qry .= "($value['firstname'],$value['lastname']), "; 
}
```

Answer (score 0):

```
for ($i =0; $i< count($date); $i++ ) 
{
   $data =  array(
                 'date' => $date[$i]
                 );
   $rs =$this->db->insert('table_name', $data);
}
```

Comment: While this code block may answer the question, it would be best if you could provide some explanation for why it does so.

Comment: this is very simple friend ... you just have to put the query inside the loop after array rplace ( $rs =$this->db->insert('table_name', $data);) with your sql query and run .. here i've used codeignitor you can use it with the simple sql query...

Answer (score 0):

Use :

```
 $start = "";
  for($i=0;$i<=$count1;$i++){

        $start .= date("Y-m-d H:i:s",strtotime("+30 minutes",strtotime($start))).',';

        echo $start;
    }


 $sql = "insert into `jqcalendar` (`list_id`,`totaltime`, `isalldayevent`) 
     values ('"
     .$list_id."', '".$start."', '".mysql_real_escape_string($ade)."'
     )";
```